# Calling free on a pointer to an element of an array declared dynamically

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, free

When I run the following code:

```
int main(int* argc, char** argv) {
    int* array = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    free(array + 3);
}
```

I get the error `pointer being freed was not allocated`. My intuition is that instead of trying to free the fourth element of `array`, `free` tried to free the thing living `3*sizeof(int)` bytes after its last element. Is this correct? If so, then why does this happen? And is the behaviour resulting from the execution of this programme always predictable, or is it undefined of implementation-specific?

Comment: See [Dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) and [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Why not just `free(array)`?

Comment: @klutt — I am not trying to do anything, just to understand what happens when you run this code and whether or not its behaviour defined.

Comment: @Olak Dietsche — Thank you! So if I understand correctly, my example corresponds to the paragraph "The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc()"?

Comment: When you run this code you invoke *undefined behavior*. Only specific addresses returned by documented library functions (`malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, `strdup`, `getline`, etc) can be passed to `free`. you can't substitute in some address in some *range* somewhere after one of those specific addresses. in this case the value of `array` is the only legal value you acquired from one of those functions, and the only legal value you can send to `free`. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free` expects you to use the very same address returned from `malloc` or otherwise anything might happen. The `malloc` call allocates a whole segment per call, in this case 5 `int` large. It doesn't make sense to free up parts of this segment, that's not how the heap works.

Heaps first allocate a segment header  which is internal information that contains size etc. Then after that header, all the data. This header part isn't visible to the programmer and how it is implemented is OS and/or C library specific.

Indeed in your case you pass an address which sits `3*sizeof(int)` bytes into the data part of the segment, which isn't a valid address since free needs the initial address used by `malloc` in order to know where the internal header of that segment starts. When you pass the wrong address to it, it might grab some other part of random data and treat that as the header. The behavior is undefined.

(You can however pass a null pointer to `free()` and that's guaranteed to be a no-op.)

Answer (score 1):

From specification of `free()`:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void free(void*ptr);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.  Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, what you're trying to do is undefined behavior

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` allocates a block of memory.

You can only de-allocate (`free`) this block. You cannot free individual elements or a part of the block.

You can re-allocate (`realloc`) this block to make it larger or smaller.

Comment: Thank you. Will it always throw the error which I have mentioned, or is it undefined?

Comment: It will always throw this error. It probably compares the pointer you give it to known allocated blocks.

Comment: @user8171079 This error message is an implementation detail. "The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc() (since C11). "